# Is there a way to set/change the changeSet (changelog) content from pipeline script? Needed for preflight type of job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a preflight job using perforce in which I retrieve a branch, unshelve (apply) a given changelist on it and then build to validate that the change in question has not broken the build.  Very similar to what you would do for a GitHub Pull Request type of CI.

I use the official checkout() pipeline call to get the branch as it simplify dealing with the perforce creds, and that causes the jenkins build to include the changelog of that branch in the build.  Yet, those are of no interest to me, as my interest is on the changelist I am unshelving on top of that branch.

Can I, from the pipeline script clear and fill the currentBuild.changeSet? If so, would someone have an example and which fields I can set under currentBuild.changeSet.items?

Or doing is only possible by going through the plugin road in the same way the p4/git plugins are doing this?

Answer (score 1):

My advice, don't play with the currentBuild.changeSet. It also contains the changeset of the shared libraries you are using. I personally don't rely on that anymore.

However, here is an article on how to update the changeSet
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217630098-How-to-access-Changelogs-in-a-Pipeline-Job-

Here is an exemple on how to implement that in a pipeline

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-58441

Finally, in an ideal world, don't share your jenkins with management or non developers/testers, share only a dashboard that is connected to a database that you filled with the relevant information you need. I use influxdb+grafana to do that with the influxdb plugin